# A question about implementation of std::shuffle using URBG

Tags: c++, random, shuffle

With reference to the (possible) implementation of the third version of `std::shuffle` template as outlined in [std::random_shuffle, std::shuffle](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle),

```
template<class RandomIt, class URBG>
void shuffle(RandomIt first, RandomIt last, URBG&& g)
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<RandomIt>::difference_type diff_t;
    typedef std::uniform_int_distribution<diff_t> distr_t;
    typedef typename distr_t::param_type param_t;

    distr_t D;
    diff_t n = last - first;
    for (diff_t i = n-1; i > 0; --i) {
        using std::swap;
        swap(first[i], first[D(g, param_t(0, i))]);
    }
}
```

I was trying to understand how the `URBG` object `g` is used along with `std::uniform_int_distribution<diff_t>` to get a result within the closed range `[g, param_t(0, i)]`:

```
swap(first[i], first[D(g, param_t(0, i))]);
```

Based on the explanation for `distr_t::param_type` provided under [C++ named requirements: RandomNumberDistribution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomNumberDistribution):

> Given
>
> - P, the type named by D::param_type
> - d, a value of type D
> - p, a (possibly const) value of type P
> - g, g1, g2, lvalues of a type satisfying UniformRandomBitGenerator
>
> The following expressions must be valid and have their specified effects:
>
> d(g,p) The sequence of numbers returned by successive invocations of
>   this call with the same g are randomly distributed according to the
>   distribution parametrized by p

since in the above invocation:

```
swap(first[i], first[D(g, param_t(0, i))]);
```

the distribution parametrized by `param_t(0, i)` always falls within the required distribution range, the invocation of `g` should also generate a random result type (int) within the distribution range.

Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Perhaps learning about [the pseudo-random generators and distributions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) would be a first step.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. `g` is only the random bit generator. The call `D(g, param_t(0, i))` produces a random number between 0 and `i`.

Comment: Yes, the example is doing a [Fisher Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm) shuffle